# calculating a compound interest in php

Tags: php

The formula for compound interest is

```
A = P(1 + r/n) ^ nt
```

Now, if I invest $60,000 for 1 year at 15%, my interest gained would be $9000.

If I add it to my initial $60,000 the the final amount = $69,000.

Here's my problem: if the year is more than one year, I want to add my initial $60,000 to the final amount of $69000 to get a new value, $129000, which i will multiply with 15% to get a new interest value of $19,350 and add it to the new value, $129,000, to get a new amount = $148350. and this will continue for the number of years specified.

```
Year 1 = $60000 + $9000 = $69000
Year 2 = $69000 + $60000 = $129000
  ($129000*15%=$19350)
  $129000+$19350 =$148350
Year 3 = $148350 + $60000 = $208350
  ($208350*15%=$31252.50)
  $208350+$31252.50 =$239602.50
```

...
Etc

Comment: <?php
if (isset($_POST['initial'])) {
$initial=$_POST["initial"];
$rate=$_POST["rate"];
$years=$_POST["years"];
$yr=12;
$message = "<font color=\"red\">Please enter details as required!
</font>";
if ($initial=="") { echo $message; }
elseif ($rate=="") { echo $message; }
elseif ($years=="") { echo $message; }
else {
$basic=$initial*$yr;
$int=$basic*$rate/100;
echo "Contributions=" .$initial." Rate=" .$rate." Year=" .$years." interest gained=".$int."<br />"; 
for ($i=1; $i<=$years; $i++) {
amount=$basic*pow(1+$rate/100,$i);
echo "Year " .$i." Earnings = " .number_format($amount,2)."<br />";}}}?>

Comment: Your understanding of interest appears off. Year two would not be 129,000. It would be 69,000. Year two's interest would be 10,350. Year three would begin with 79,350. Your example numbers use an interest rate of **115%**. *Oh, this question is six years old. Oops*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a recursive function, assuming same yearly investment

```
<?php

function interest($investment,$year,$rate=15,$n=1){
    $accumulated=0;
    if ($year > 1){
            $accumulated=interest($investment,$year-1,$rate,$n);
            }
    $accumulated += $investment;
    $accumulated = $accumulated * pow(1 + $rate/(100 * $n),$n);
    return $accumulated;
    }

?>
```

Then to run the function according to form input

```
<html>
<head><title>Calculate Compound Interest</title></head>
<body><h3>Calculate Compound Interest</h3>

<?php
$initial=0;
$years=0;
$rate=15;
$n=1;

if (isset($_POST['initial'])){$initial=$_POST['initial'];}
if (isset($_POST['years'])){$years=$_POST['years'];}
if (isset($_POST['rate'])){$rate=$_POST['rate'];}
if (isset($_POST['n'])){$n=$_POST['n'];}

if (isset($_POST['initial'])){
    echo "After ". $years. " years, the accumulated interest is ". interest($initial,$years,$rate,$n)."\n";
}
?>
```

And the form input

```
<?php echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\""  . $_POST['SELF.PHP'] . "\">"; ?>

<p>Initial amount (contribution), $: <?php echo '<input type="number" name="initial" value='. $initial.' required/>'?> </p>
<p> Annual interest rate : <?php echo '<input type="number" name="rate" value='.$rate.' />' ?> % </p>
<p> Number of compounding periods per year? <?php echo '<input type="number" name="n" value='.$n.' />'?> </p>
<p> How many years? <?php echo '<input type="number" name="years" value='. $years.' min="1" required/>' ?></p>
<p> <input type="submit" value="Generate compound interest table."/> </p>
</form> </body> </html>
```

EDIT: edited to include example of running function with a form input

Comment: this is how i tried to use it.
<html >
<head><title>Calculate Compound Interest</title></head>
<body><h3>Calculate Compound Interest</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
  <p>Initial amount (contribution), $:
    <input type="text" name="initial" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Annual interest rate : 
      <input type="text" name="rate" />
  %  </p>
  <p>
    How many years? 
      <input type="text" name="years" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate compound interest table." onClick="interest($investment,$year,$rate=15,$n=1)" />
  </p>
</form>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: i've edited my answer to show the full php script with form input

Comment: This is quite different from the first example you gave. The amount and following year is not reflected as you did before.

Comment: the code can be seen in action [here](http://rjg70.user.srcf.net/test/test.php) after submitting information, you get a line printing out the information as before. The function is the same, but now with inclusion of adjustable rate and adjustable compounding periods

Comment: if (isset($_POST['initial'])){$initial=$_POST['initial']*12;}      that is how i fixed it. thank you very much, i appreciate. more tutor from you. :)

Comment: np, happy to help. In your fix, `$initial=$_POST['initial']*12` is just taking your investment amount and multiplying it by 12. Can you not just enter a larger value in the form rather than do the multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

First you get the post values as

```
<?php
$principal = $_POST['principal'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];
?>
```

You may calculate by defining a function by considerin decimals:

```
<?php

function compound_interest($principal, $year, $interest){
    $converted_interest = $interest / 100;
    $completed_interest = $converted_interest + 1;
    $exponent = pow($completed_interest,$year);
    $final = $principal * $exponent;
    return number_format((float)$final, 2, ',', '.');
}

?>
```

Lastly, run the function:

```
<?php $calculate = compound_interest($principal, $year, $interest); echo $calculate; ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your help is welcome, but this question is years old. You could improve your answer by explaining how you're using exponents/powers rather than loops/recursion. Still, here's an upvote to start you on your journey! PS, personally I like your method better.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below upgraded one fixed for multiple years

```
<?php
// PHP program to find
// compound interest for
// given values.

$years = 10; // number of years
$initial = 10000; // Principal amount
$rate = 10; // Rate of Interest
$n =4; // number of compounding in a year

function CompoundInterest($investment, $year, $rate=10, $n=1)
{
    $accumulated=0;
    if ($year > 1)
    {
        // print_r($investment);
        $accumulated = CompoundInterest($investment, $year-1 , $rate, $n);
    }else {
        $accumulated += $investment;
    }

    $accumulated = $accumulated * pow(1 + $rate/(100 * $n),$n);
    return $accumulated;
}

$totalMaturity = CompoundInterest($initial,$years,$rate,$n);
echo "Deposit Amount is ". $initial."\n";
echo '<br>';
echo "After ". $years. " years, the accumulated interest is ". $totalMaturity."\n";
echo '<br>';
echo "After ". $years. " years, Interest is ". ($totalMaturity - $initial) ."\n";

?>
```